# Jquery part is not working. Division is not fading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Division is not fading In or Out.

I tried both the cases. But its not working. I want to fadeIn and fadeOut division "submenu1" and "submenu2".

Initially i have display to none for both division.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
      <title>
          cheaphotel.com
      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#submenu1").fadeIn("slow");      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maindiv">
        <img src="Capture1.jpg" height="150px" alt="logo" width="200px">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label id="username">Username:</label></td>
                <td><input type="email" id="emaillog" name="emaillog"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label id="password">Password:</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" id="passlog" name="passlog"></td>
            </tr>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login">
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <button id="home">Home</button>
        <button id="facilities">Facilities</button>
        <button id="booking">Booking</button>
        <button id="aboutus">About Us</button>
        <button id="contactus">Contact Us</button>
    </div>
    <div id="submenu1" class="submenu1">
        <button id="room">Room</button>
        <button id="decors">Decors</button>
        <button id="meeting">Meeting room</button>
    </div>
    <div id="submenu2">
        <button id="availability">Availability</button>
        <button id="status">Booking status</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know what it is you exactly want to achieve but this works: http://jsfiddle.net/w0xsr3ge/1/

Comment: You have the script in the head, when it runs, the body hasn't even started loading, so the div doesn't even exist. Either move your script to the bootm of the body, or wrap it like this `$(function() { $("#submenu1").fadeIn("slow"); });` to delay running it until the page has loaded

Answer (score 1):

The script should work when your dom is loaded and ready. So keep your script inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // here...
});
```

It will wait until the dom is loaded and then execute the script.

Another point is to make the [***.fadeIn()***](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) work you need to keep the submenu1 section already hidden.

So the script should be something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submenu1").hide();  // hide it first
    $("#submenu1").fadeIn("slow");  // slowly fadeIn
    $("#submenu2").fadeOut("slow");  // fadeOut #submenu2
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/0jv40p2m/)

Comment: wouldn't call that a workaround, I'd call that a solution - workaround makes it sound like a kludge :p

Comment: but if i want to add mouseover function, how should i do that?

Comment: @Abhishek, use jQuery `.mouseover()` function. Have a look at their documentation here : https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like as shown in this fiddle.

You have to first `.hide()` that element so that it can be `.fadeIn()` later.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pjqhh479/1/)